# Internal Temperature Sensor Reading of STM32 only updating after Reset

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, stm32cubemx

We are reading Internal Temperature Sensor reading of STM32-F410RB - NUCLEO 64 Board.

**Problem:**

Getting the reading of Temperature sensor every 1 second as programmed, but the same readings are got.
Only when Reset is done, the Temperature Reading get updated

[image]

**Current Setup**

1. Windows 10 64bit
2. STM32 Nucleo 64 - F410RB
3. Using CubeMX IDE
4. PuTTy for Serial Monitoring

**STM32 CUBE MX IDE Configurations Done**

1. System Core - Serial Wire
2. Analog - ADC1 - Enabled Temperature Sensor Channel
   Parameter Settings - ADC Setting - Scan Conversion & Continues Conversion Enabled
   Rank - Sample Time - 480 Cycles
3. USART2 - 9600 Baud Rate

**CODE Snippet of Main**

```
int main(void)
{
  
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);

  while (1)
  {
      uint16_t readValue;
      float tCelsius;
      readValue = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
      tCelsius = ((float)readValue) * 3300.0 / 4095.0; // To mV
      tCelsius = (tCelsius - 500.0) / 10.0; // To degrees C
      UART_SEND_TXT(&huart2, "Temperature = ", 0);
      UART_SEND_FLT(&huart2, tCelsius, 1);
      HAL_Delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Please kindly help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sounds like the ADC is incorrectly configured for manually starting each read. For this kind of application you'll want continuous conversion.

Comment: Lundin, Thanks for the prompt reply. I will definitely recheck the config and see.

Comment: Possibly you did not configure `MX_ADC1_Init()` for continuous mode?  That is generated by CubeMX from the parameters and options you select.  ``MX_ADC1_Init()`` should contain `hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE` among other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one `HAL_ADC_Start` outside the loop. Therefore conversion starts only once.

Inside the loop you just repeatedly receive the last result of the conversion by `HAL_ADC_GetValue`.

You need to start regular group conversion by calling `HAL_ADC_Start` each time, then wait conversion to end by `HAL_ADC_PollForConversion` and, at last, get the result by `HAL_ADC_GetValue`

Comment: A proper HAL which actually works as a hardware abstraction layer would do this for you. Anyway as already mentioned, the OP is just interested in grabbing a number once every second so manually starting a conversion is wrong - they should be using continuous conversion and just grab the last read value.